# How to edit multiple .mat files in a folder using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io

I am trying to edit 100 .mat files in a folder with no pattern in their names. Each file contains a matrix of size *100*-by-*10*, and I want to convert them to *10*-by-*10*-by-*10*. How do I go about this?

Comment: Please specify how would you like to select the files, how would you like to cut the matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you have a single matrix in each file, and want to overwrite the original matrix:

```
listing = dir('*.mat'); % finds all .mat files in your pwd
for ii = 1:numel(listing)
    tmp = listing(ii).name;
    s = load(tmp); % load a file
    Fname = fieldnames(s); % get matrix name
    out = reshape(s.(Fname{1}),[10 10 10]); % reshape
    save(tmp,'out') % Save, overwriting original
end
```